# ImportError and Django driving me crazy

Tags: python, django, django-models, importerror

OK, I have the following directory structure (it's a django project):

```
-> project
--> app
```

and within the app folder, there is a scraper.py file which needs to reference a class defined within models.py

I'm trying to do the following:

```
import urllib2
import os
import sys
import time
import datetime
import re
import BeautifulSoup

sys.path.append('/home/userspace/Development/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

from project.app.models import ClassName
```

and this code just isn't working.  I get an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 14, in 
    from project.app.models import ClassName
ImportError: No module named project.app.models
```

This code above used to work, but broke somewhere along the line and I'm extremely confused as to why I'm having problems.  On SnowLeopard using python2.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append ('/path/to/the/project')
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)

from app.models import MyModel
```

Comment: OK, I think this worked.  I'm saying "think" because the model in question requires TineyMCE and it's barfing on an issue with that:

"ImportError: cannot import name smart_unicode"

Would it be possible to explain exactly what setup_environ(settings) does?

Comment: Having read `django\core\management\__init__.py`, I found that `setup_environ` 1. sets `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']`; 2. imports the `project` as a module.

Comment: How do you import `smart_unicode`? Can the module with the function be found in the importing file’s dir or in `sys.path`?

Comment: I figured it out.  Painful.  I had the library importing smart_unicode installed within the python2.5 system libraries AND in my project.  Once I got that resolved, everything works!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whoa whoa whoa. You should never **ever** have to put your project name in any of your app code. You should be able to reuse app code across multiple projects with no changes. Pinax does this really well and I highly recommend checking it out for a lot of django best practices.

The worst thing you could do here is to hard code your absolute path into your app or settings. You shouldn't do this because it will break during deployment unless you do some `import local_settings` hacking.

If you have to access the project root directory, try what pinax has in settings.py...

```
import os.path
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

The thing is that it looks like you are trying to access the models module within the same app and this is waaay easier.

To import models.py inside scraper.py in the same directory just use `import models` or `import models as app_models` if you already have something named models in scraper.py (django.db.models for instance). Are you familiar with Python module conventions?

However, the best way is probably to stick with the django idiom, from ... import ... statement:

```
from app import models
```

If this doesn't work automatically, then something is wrong in your settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate if `project` is located in `/home/userspace/Development/`.  I'll assume that it is.

Make sure there's an (empty by default) file named `__init__.py` in `project` and another one in `app`.

**EDIT:** Next thing to try: Fire up the Python command line in the script's directory and try the following:

```
import project
import project.app as app
import project.app.models as models
models.__dict__.keys()
```

Do they all work?  If so, what is the last line's output?  If not, which dies first?

Comment: You're correct that project is located in /home/userspace/Development and there is an empty __init__.py in both folders.

Comment: "import project" doesn't work.

ImportError: No module named "project"

it was an __init__.py (not init.py, sorry about that)